# django form is submitting but the object is not saved in the database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Actually i'm working on the library management system project everything is working fine except return book functionality. My project contains books, students and issue and returning the book with fine if it is there. I was making a return book function i made the logic but and it is correct also but it is not saving into the database. Even the calculations which i wanted is done but it is not submitting. I'm doing from last 3 days. Please help me, if you get some idea. And please, let me know if you required any other files.

models.py for return Book

```
class ReturnBook(models.Model):
    actual_return_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fine_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book.book_name + ' is returned by ' + self.student_name.first_name + ' ' + self.student_name.last_name
```

forms.py for return book

```
class ReturnBookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReturnBook
        fields = [
            'actual_return_date',
            'book',
            'student_name',
            'fine_amount'
        ]
```

urls.py for return book and returned book

```
path('issuedbooks/<int:pk>/returnbook/', views.returnBook, name='return-book'),
path('returnedbook/', views.TransactionandReturnBook, name='returned-book'),
```

returnbookform.html

```
{% extends "lms/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="section">
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'returned-book' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">

            <div class="card mt-4 detail-view-header">
                <h3 class="text-center mt-2 font-weight-bold" style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 25px;">Return
                    Book here </h3>
            </div>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Return Book</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py for return book

```
@login_required
def returnBook(request, pk):

    obj = get_object_or_404(Issue, id=pk)
    print(obj)
    fine = 0
    d1 = date.today()
    d2 = obj.expected_return_date
    diff_date = d2.day - d1.day
    print(diff_date)
    if diff_date > 0:
        fine = diff_date*2

    book = Book.objects.get(book_name=obj.book)
    print(book)
    book.available_copies = book.available_copies + 1
    book.save()

    fname = obj.student_name.first_name
    print(fname)

    student = Student.objects.get(first_name=fname)
    print(student)
    student.no_of_issued_books = student.no_of_issued_books - 1
    student.save()

    initial_dict = {
        'book' : obj.book,
        'student_name': obj.student_name,
        'actual_return_date': datetime.today,
        'fine_amount': obj.fine_amount,
    }

    form = ReturnBookForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_dict)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'You have returned the book')
        return redirect('returned-book')

    Issue.objects.filter(id=obj.id).delete()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }   
    return render(request, 'lms/returnbook_form.html', context)
```

models.py for issue book

```
def get_expected_return_date():
    return datetime.today() + timedelta(days=30)

class Issue(models.Model):
    student_name = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
    expected_return_date = models.DateField(default=get_expected_return_date)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book.book_name + ' issued for ' + self.student_name.first_name + ' ' + self.student_name.last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong actions in forms.Use the **{% url 'return-book' %}** instead of  **{% url 'returned-book' %}**

Comment: i did that but it gave the another error i. e. NoReverseMatch at /issuedbooks/40/returnbook/